# "Do not allow drive redirection" not available for non-administrative user policy

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server

I'm trying to define a local group policy to prevent non-administrator users from moving data off of a cloud VM.

I added the `Local Computer\Non-Administrators Policy` snap-in via MMC, but when I drill down into ...

User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection

... I see "Do not allow Clipboard redirection", but I do not see "Do not allow drive redirection".

How can I set this to Enabled for only non-administrators?

Comment: Is this under User policy or Computer policy? Check the other one.

Comment: I see it under Computer Configuration, but not User Configuration, which leads to my question.  Why can't I set this at the User Configuration level?

Comment: Because it isn't a user level config.

Comment: So if I only want to allow drive redirection for Administrators, is there a way to achieve that using policies? Or is there a different way?